# Returning string from JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to return a string from native. For that I'm using the following code.

Native:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_test_Demo_getString(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "hello");
}
```

Java:

```
private native String getString(); //in com.test.Demo
```

After this I'm generating .so files using `ndk-build` and including them in `jniLibs`.

However, the string returned is null. Any ideas on what is wrong ?

Comment: Nope. Just returns null value. Most likely, it can't link native method.

Comment: try JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_test_Demo_getString(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaThis) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "hello");
}

Comment: @samgak I also found this on some tutorial yesterday. Luckily, this works but I don't know why  ! Can you explain this ?

Comment: JNIEXPORT is used to include the function in the dynamic table of the .so file so that it can be linked at runtime. JNICALL is used to specify the calling convention (it actually does nothing on Android because the default one is correct). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422660/when-to-use-jniexport-and-jnicall-in-android-ndk)

Comment: What is wrong is almost certainly that you aren't executing this code.