# Clang does not strip symbols for local static libraries

Tags: android-ndk, clang

Using `Android NDK r18b` (with `clang` tool chain) and `Android Studio 3.2.1`.

Relevant part of my `mylib.gradle`:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "${ndkDir}/ndk-build${ndkExt}"
}
```

My `Application.mk`:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-17
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
# APP_OPTIM := release
APP_CFLAGS += -D_BSD_SOURCE
```

And relevant part of my `Android.mk`:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(BASE_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE := mylib_jni

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
  lib1 \
  lib2

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
  mylib_wrap \
  other_wrap

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The static library `mylib_jni.so` is successfully built. I then run the following command (from the NDK):

> arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -a mylib_jni.so

---

### Symbols not stripped

In the output I can see the names of all non-static methods in `lib1` and `lib2` (not *whole* libraries as can be seen above). **How is this possible?** How can I get some outputs from the `ndk-build` command with information about why the symbols are not stripped? (I cannot find the `options.txt` for my NDK build step.)

Comment: There's not really enough information here. Which libraries are you examining? There are two out directories with ndk-build, libs and obj, and the libraries in obj are not stripped. The other unknown is whether those symbols even should be stripped. If they are used (or I think if they are in a section with a symbol that is used) then they should not be stripped. You can run `ndk-build V=1` to see the commands that are run and strip will be one of them. FYI, Clang is not responsible for stripping; strip is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am afraid you are confused between **strip** and **visibility=hidden**.

The [former](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_(Unix)) is a separate, post-linker, step of building a shared library. Its purpose is to reduce the size of the file (which will be packed into APK) by removing some extra information that the linker leaves for debugging purposes. Note that **gradle** (in Android Studio 3.2+) performs this strip even later, when the native libraries from all modules are merged together.

Strip affects the size of the file, but not the [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) of symbols.

Hiding symbols is another technique to reduce the size of the binaries. It is also highly recommended, to reduce exposure of your libraries to reverse engineering.

This does not happen by default. You must explicitly add this compiler flag:

```
APP_CFLAGS += -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
```

You may combine this with discarding of unused functions:

```
APP_CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
APP_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
```

You must explicitly mark the external functions with

```
__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
```

Luckily, thanks to **jni.h**, this attribute is set for all `JNIEXPORT` funcitons.

If you use prebuilt static libraries, you [may need also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863432/192373)

```
APP_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL
```

Consider also providing [version script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50637280/192373)

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,-version-script -Wl,mylib_jni.vs
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answer! Thanks a lot! `fvisibility=hidden` is the feature I was looking for.

Comment: The `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` removed pretty much everything, resulting in a corrupt lib. The other settings worked! But still, I can see a number of **libc** entries - e.g. `free@LIBC` - in the symbol table. Are these required or can they also be hidden somehow?

Comment: It's strange that `exclude-libs` produces a currupt result. You can run **ndk-build -B -V** and step by step find what specifically went wrong.

Comment: As for references to **libc** and other system libraries, this is definitely expected. These are for functions that your library *needs*, not what it provides. NDK allows you to build your library with static linkage to **libc**, **libm**, etc. Note that NDK does not provide **liblog.a** for `__android_log_print()` and her kin.

Comment: My library got "corrupt" in the way that almost everything was stripped (size reduced by 95% or so). Linking **libc** statically is certainly a wanted option in my case, but haven't succeded with that so far. What is the flag for that?

Comment: I believe, **ALL** includes `libmylib_wrap.a` and `libother_wrap.a`. But you can try `-Wl,--exclude-libs,lib1 -Wl,--exclude-libs,lib2`

Comment: let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183284/room-for-alex-cohn-and-l33t)

Comment: it seem "-fvisibility=hidden" flags only hide the normal function name, but let the global function variable keep its name.( like void (*func1)(); )